# Magento 2.3.4 + Varnish 6

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, varnish

I am having a problem with Magento open source 2.3.4 and its configuration to work with varnish 6. I have followed the devdocs about setting up varnish caching. I have verified that the varnish part works well with nginx and php-fpm by verifying that it works with a small demo page. The only part that is not working is Magento 2.3.4.

The nginx error log shows the following error:

```
2020/03/03 14:32:34 [error] 7273#7273: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/var/page_cache" is not writable in /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/usr...')
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/usr/share/ngin...')
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
#4 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, tr" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com"
```

It is clear that magento thinks it should be using its built in full page cache because it is trying to access `var/page_cache`. A correct installation using varnish would not be attempting to access this directory.

I have configured magento to use varnish. Does anybody have any insight as to why it is not working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

you mistaken this functionality.

first of all you must have proper permissions set and access rights, no matter how cache is configured.

second you need to check your `app/etc/env.php` configuration file, it will tell you exactly where cache and session storage is.

then after you change settings you can manually flush caches to apply new settings

Comment: The permissions on the `var/page_cache` directory are the same as when I use the built-in cache so the permissions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

According to dev docs as of march 2019 v4 and v5 of varnish are supported. Can anyone confirm version 6 will work?

This could be your problem?

Comment: Magento 2.3 will generate a vcl file for varnish 6 which I assume implies that varnish 6 is supported. I went with the assumption that the docs hadn't been updated.

Comment: Yes solid assumption. If you figure it out might be worth submitting pull request to dev docs https://github.com/magento/devdocs save others similar pain

Comment: I have back ported my ansible script to install varnish v4 and it does not fix the problem. Will submit a fix to devdocs as and when I manage to fix this.

Comment: Have submitted a documentation fix [here](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/pull/6837).

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in an earlier reply: Magento has multiple caches and you'r probably confusing the built-in cache, with Varnish page caching.

## The error you're getting

As the error indicates, you need to make sure the `/usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/var/page_cache` folder is writeable on your system. You could execute the following command to make this happen: `chmod 744 /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/var/page_cache`.

## Regarding Varnish

As far as Varnish is concerned: please read [the Varnish *what's new* page](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/whats-new/index.html#varnish-6-0) to learn about new features and compatibility. Some of the brand new features are now part of the `vcl 4.1` syntax and can only be run if you explicitly mention this version in your VCL file.

Magento will probably generate VCL files that have the `vcl 4.0` syntax. This makes sure you don't have any incompatibility.

Comment: Am using the VCL files generated by Magento for my installed version of varnish. I think you are right with regards to the wrong cache being configured but I did follow to the letter the instructions in devdocs so either I am incapable of following devdocs instructions properly or devdocs is wrong or there's a bug lingering in Magento that I am bumping in to.

Comment: Re the `var/page_cache` the permissions are exactly the same as when I was using built-in cache which worked absolutely fine. I even tried setting it to 777 and it made no difference. The only thing left to do is to debug the code. It is the only thing that I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by a change to selinux. The default setting in the image I use from my ISP for selinux used to be switched off by default. That changed in the last week or so to enforced by default.